# Trying to access data in the movies file and use it in the home file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access data in the movies const in the movies.js file and use the data in my home.js file.
I tried importing it but it's not working. Anyone that could have a look?

My home file (where:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import movies$ from "./movies"

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // <div>Charles</div>
            <div>{this.movies$[0].title}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

---

```
const movies = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Oceans 8',
    category: 'Comedy',
    likes: 4,
    dislikes: 1
  }, {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Midnight Sun',
    category: 'Comedy',
    likes: 2,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    id: '6',
    title: 'Pulp Fiction',
    category: 'Thriller',
    likes: 11,
    dislikes: 3
  }
]

export const movies$ = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, movies))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In movies .js:

```
export const movies = [
{
  id: '1',
  title: 'Oceans 8',
  category: 'Comedy',
  likes: 4,
  dislikes: 1
}, {
  id: '2',
  title: 'Midnight Sun',
  category: 'Comedy',
  likes: 2,
  dislikes: 0
}, {
  id: '6',
  title: 'Pulp Fiction',
  category: 'Thriller',
  likes: 11,
  dislikes: 3
 }
];
```

In home.js

```
import { movies } from './movies.js';
// in component
<div>{movies[0].title}</div>
```

Comment: thanks! It still gives me: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". How do I access it/use it in components?

Comment: I have updated answer. Please accept answer if it answers your question